# php use an array to pass in arguments to a dynamic function

Tags: php, url-routing

I've searched the web high and low for any answer on this, but have found nothing.

Here is what I'm trying to accomplish:

I have a routing function in an mvc framework, and currently this is how arguments are being passed into the function.

```
$this->url_controller->{$this->url_action}($this->url_parameter_1, $this->url_parameter_2, $this->url_parameter_3);
```

It's good, but limits it to only 3 parameters, or how ever many I hard code in. I would like to make this function more dynamic. The actual function that it's calling is expecting 4 arguments. What I would like to do is this:

```
$params = array();
foreach( $this->url_parameters as $key => $value ):
    if($key == 0) continue;
    if($key == 1) continue;
    $params[] = $this->url_parameters[$key];
endforeach;
$this->url_controller->{$this->url_action}($params);
```

Now I understand why this doesn't work. I've tried using call_user_func_array() but because of the dynamic naming it wouldn't work correctly. I'm also trying to avoid using func_get_args() on the receiving end to keep things simple.

Any help is appreciated. :)

Comment: Try looking at [`call_user_func_array`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php)

Comment: What does `$this->url_controller` contain? Is that the name of the controller, or the loaded controller class?

Comment: Is your controller function expecting an array??? seems to me that the answer is no

Comment: No it is not expecting an array.

Answer (score 0):

Use [func_get_args()](https://www.php.net/func_get_args) in the receiving end to process all arguments, then just loop through because it's an array.